# How to select first, second value with XPATH?

Tags: xpath

I have a website and want to select some element; here is my XPATH expression:

```
//span[contains(.,"Arbeitsräume")]
```

which returns two matches. The first match probably comes from this html code piece:

```
 <span class="menu-item-text">                       
     <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
     Arbeitsräume
 </span>
```

The second match I do not know. However, I want to select the first match. Therefore I tried:

```
//span[contains(.,"Arbeitsräume")][1]
```

which again gave TWO matches. A '0' or a '2' in the bracket returned no matches.

I though a square bracket at the end of the xpath expression lets you select the first, second, ... match, but I might be mistaken.

So how can I select the first, second... XPATH match?

Comment: try `(//span[contains(.,"Arbeitsräume")])[1]` to ensure that the `[1]` applies to the whole expression

Comment: Ah I see. Seems to work, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(//span[contains(.,"Arbeitsräume")])[1]
```

The expression `//span[1]` selects the first `span` child of every element containing spans. For example, given the following document

```
<doc>
    <div>
        <span id="1.1"/>
        <span id="1.2"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span id="2.1"/>
        <span id="2.2"/>
    </div>
</doc>
```

two `span` elements with ids 1.1 and 2.1 are selected. `(//span)[1]` on other hand only returns the first `span` element in the whole document.